# Функция возвращает значение Number вместо String

Tags: javascript

Задача такая: получить факториал числа и вернуть его длину. Разумеется я перевожу число в строку и после применяю метод toString, или объект String, или конкатенирую число с пустой строкой "" и применяю свойство length, то в итоге я получаю ЧИСЛО 1 в данном примере:

```
function count(n) {
let num = (n ? n * count(n - 1) : 1).toString().length;
return num;
}
console.log(count(5));
```

Особо примечательно то, что если вызвать результат факториала числа !5 = 120 к примеру через console.log или alert, без разницы - то дает то что нужно - длину 3. Пробовал разбивать строковое число в массив и выводить его длину, в итоге дает число 1.

Как преобразовать длину числа в ДАННОЙ функции?

Comment: потому что .length() return number

Comment: не понял, но за ответ спасибо... ;)

Comment: А зачем надо переводить что-то в строку вообше?

Comment: Это задача такая на C**D**W**S. У них задачи со странностями. Тренируюсь

Comment: А что за странная задача посчитать факториал и вернуть длину? Функция как минимум должна делать что-то конкретное. Например считать факториал. Другая функция считает длину числа.

Comment: Понятно....... .

Comment: отличительно то, что ее решило около 92% пользователей

Comment: На мой взгляд если такая прям задача, то воспользоваться замыканием и сделать функцию в функции. В итоге внутренняя будет считать факториал, А сама запускаемая уже длину из внутренней. Чтобы не костылить и не смешивать действия

Comment: твоя функция не считает факториал, поэтому и результаты разные

Comment: Попробую сейчас так. Надеюсь решится

Comment: function count(n) {
    return n ? n * count(n - 1) : 1;
} Считает. Почему не считает, вы думаете?

Comment: @Slon, в текущем виде считает. А в вопросе у тебя **другая** функция ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: то есть вы предлагаете ее решить замыканием?

Comment: можно и без замыкания. Суть в том, чтобы функция делала то, что требуется в задаче. Сейчас - не делает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function count(num) {

    const factorial = n => (n ? n * factorial(n - 1) : 1);

    return factorial(num).toString().length;
}

console.log(count(5));
```

Comment: На данный момент это лучший способ. Выше применялась функция только для определенного числа - 5. Спасибо что заморочились, у себя зафиксирую.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот так

```js
function count(n) {
  let num = (n ? n * count(n - 1) : 1);
  return num;
}
console.log(count(5).toString().length);
```

Comment: Это решается! Но есть нюанс - на том сайте стоит свой интерпретатор js и он не подразумевает браузерных команд. Задача должна решиться возвратом значения с этой функции. За ответ спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Тогда на скорую руку вот так, код можно сократить, для наглядности, то есть тут явное понимание рекурсии

```js
function count(n) {
  let num = (n ? n * count(n - 1) : 1);
  if (n === 5) {
    return num.toString().length;
  }
  return num
}
console.log(count(5));
```

Comment: Верно, слушайте. Благодарю!

Comment: @Slon, эта функция работает только с вызовом `count(5)` - в любом другом вызове - будет ошибка

Comment: Успехов вам, сам в пути обучения)

Comment: Благодарю! И вам успехов!